# Can someone help me finding why the judge is throwing up "wrong answer"?

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem in Python : https://pastebin.com/xjz062uU   (Google Kickstart Round A)

Here is the code : https://pastebin.com/fxAg5JUK

Code :

```
t = int(input())  

for i in range(1, t + 1):

    number , budget = [int(s) for s in input().split(" ")]

    l = input()
    l1 = l.split()
    l1.sort()
    sum = 0
    count = 0

    for k in range(len(l1)):
        sum = sum + int(l1[k])
        if (sum> budget):
            sum = sum - int(l1[k])
            break
        else:
            count = count + 1
            continue

    print("Case #{}: {}".format(i,count))
```

I am getting correct answers on the sample input given but the judge says that my answer is incorrect. I can't seem to find the problem Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I recommend putting the description and all relevant info in the question itself.

Comment: See also [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796608/google-kickstart-wrong-answer)

Comment: Do not overwrite the built-in `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the houses' prices as strings, you'll have problems due to differing lengths of numbers because for example it'll sort an array [9, 12, 1000] as [1000, 12, 9] and will make your program fail on such a case. Instead, you need to do something along the lines of `l1 = sorted(list(map(int,input().split())))` to input the list as a list of integers and subsequently sort it.

Comment: Good call but check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796608/google-kickstart-wrong-answer) which uses an identical approach but does cast before sorting.

Comment: The difference between the two approaches is in this one, the print statement is outside the loop and will always be reached.

Comment: Ah, so the other answer fails because it doesn't print anything when there are no possible houses in the budget, and this one fails because of sorting? Good finds.

Answer (score -1):

```
i = int(input())
num = []
for j in range(i):
    l = input()
    x , y = l.split()
    y = int(y)
    m = input()
    p =[] 
    p = m.split(" ")
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    s = []
    for w in p:
        w = int(w)
        s.append(w)
    s = sorted(s)
    for q in s:
      q = int(q)
      if sum+q <= y: 
            sum += q
            count+=1
    r = count
    num.append(r)
i = 0
for op in num:
  i +=1
  j = "Case #"+str(i)+": "
  print(j,end="")
  print(op)
```

TRY USING THIS CODE