# Google KickStart Wrong Answer

Tags: python

I made a program for the Google Kickstart 2020 Round A, But it is showing wrong answer and Test set skipped.
this was the Problem

Problem

There are N houses for sale. The i-th house costs Ai dollars to buy. You have a budget of B dollars to spend.

What is the maximum number of houses you can buy?
Input

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a single line containing the two integers N and B. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai, the cost of the i-th house.
Output

For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum number of houses you can buy.
Limits

Time limit: 15 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
1 ≤ B ≤ 105.
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 1000, for all i.
Test set 1

1 ≤ N ≤ 100.
Test set 2

1 ≤ N ≤ 105.
Sample

Input

3
4 100
20 90 40 90
4 50
30 30 10 10
3 300
999 999 999

Output

Case #1: 2
Case #2: 3
Case #3: 0

In Sample Case #1, you have a budget of 100 dollars. You can buy the 1st and 3rd houses for 20 + 40 = 60 dollars.
In Sample Case #2, you have a budget of 50 dollars. You can buy the 1st, 3rd and 4th houses for 30 + 10 + 10 = 50 dollars.
In Sample Case #3, you have a budget of 300 dollars. You cannot buy any houses (so the answer is 0).

Note: Unlike previous editions, in Kick Start 2020, all test sets are visible verdict test sets, meaning you receive instant feedback upon submission.

and my code was

```
T = int(input())
caselist = []
for i in range(T):
    x = input()
    x = x.split()
    N = int(x[0])
    B = int(x[1])
    l = input()
    l = l.split()
    temp = []
    for j in l:
        temp.append(int(j))
    temp.sort()
    s = 0
    n = 0
    for k in temp:
        s+=k
        if s<=B:
            n+=1
        else:
            print('Case #'+str(i+1)+': '+str(n))
            break
```

[image: This is My output with those provided by them]
Just help me whats wrong in this..
Thankyou!

[This is what they say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stwn7.png)

Comment: This was just asked [25 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796481/can-someone-help-me-finding-why-the-judge-is-throwing-up-wrong-answer). Can you walk us through your algorithm? What test does it fail on?

Comment: They aren't showing any other details

Comment: You can monitor that thread for answers to your question but the algorithms appear identical. Hopefully they'll edit it to add details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T = int(input())
for test in range(T):
    house = []
    input1 = input()
    input1 = input1.split()
    N = int(input1[0])
    B = int(input1[1])
    input2 = input()
    input2 = input2.split()
    for x in input2:
        price = int(x)
        dictionary = {"house":x,"price":price}
        house.append(dictionary)
    
    def myFunc(e):
        return e['price']

    house.sort(key=myFunc)

    spent = 0
    purchased = 0

    for x in house:
        variable1 = x.get('price')
        spent += variable1
        if spent <= B:
            purchased += 1

    print(f"Case #{test+1}: {purchased}")
```

got past the samples and both tests

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is if you can buy all the houses you don't print the answer, since you only print once the total cost surpasses your budget. This can easily be solved by moving your print statement outside the loop, at the end of your program.

Comment: I Had it outside first.. But it still had the same problem so I put that inside and still it's like that...

Comment: I just tried submitting it with the print statement after the loop and it passed the test cases. Did you remember to keep the break statement inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 #define ll long long
 #define ar array
 int n, b, a[100000];
 void solve() 
 {
    cin >> n >> b;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    cin >> a[i];
    sort(a, a+n);
    int ans=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      if(b>=a[I]) 
    {
        b-=a[i];
        ++ans;
    }
     }
cout << ans << "\n";
}

 int main() {
ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
cin.tie(0);

int t, i=1;
cin >> t;
while(t--) {
    cout << "Case #" << i << ": ";
    solve();
    ++i;
}
}
```

Comment: it'll be great if you could explain your algo as well.

Comment: Could you provide some explanation, so others could vote you up?

Answer (score 0):

**KickStart 2020 Round A (Allocation Problem Solution) using JAVA**

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Solution {
    private static long N;
    private static long A;
    private static long B;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           N = sc.nextInt();
        for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A = sc.nextInt();
            B = sc.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Integer> houses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (long j = 0; j < A; j++) {
            houses.add(sc.nextInt());
            }
            long no_of_houses = findTheHouses(houses,B);
            System.out.println("Case #"+ (i+1) +": "+no_of_houses);

        }

        sc.close();
    }

    private static long findTheHouses(ArrayList<Integer> houses, long max_cost) {
        Collections.sort(houses);
        long count_budget =0;
        int houses_count=0;
        do{
                count_budget = count_budget +houses.get(houses_count);
            if(count_budget<=max_cost)
                houses_count++;
                else
                break;
        }while(houses.size()>houses_count);
        
    return houses_count;    
    }
}
```

[ScreenShot of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guFbx.png)

Answer (score 0):

tt = int(input())
for test_cases in range(tt):
number,budget = list(map(int,input().split()))
print(number,budget)

```
price = []
cart = []
count = 0
for h in range(number):
    price.append(int(input()))

for x in price:
    if  x <= budget:
        
        cart.append(x)
    
cart.sort()        
our_sum = sum(cart)

for y in cart:
    count+=1

if our_sum <= budget:
    print("Case #",test_cases,": ",count)
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu and welcome to Stackoverflow. While your contribution is very welcome, it's hard to understand what your code actually does with regard to the problem. Please explain the various sections of it, and how they tackle the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
tests =  int(input())
out  = []
for i in range(tests):
    inp = input().split(" ")
    num = int(inp[0])
    b = int(inp[1])
    prices = input().split(" ")
    for i in range(num):
        prices[i] = int(prices[i])
    prices.sort()
    count = 0
    for i in range(num):
        if(b-prices[i] >= 0  ):
            b = b - prices[i]
            count  = count+ 1
    
    out.append(count)
for i in out:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
i = int(input())
num = []
for j in range(i):
    l = input()
    x , y = l.split()
    y = int(y)
    m = input()
    p =[] 
    p = m.split(" ")
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    s = []
    for w in p:
        w = int(w)
        s.append(w)
    s = sorted(s)
    for q in s:
      q = int(q)
      if sum+q <= y: 
            sum += q
            count+=1
    r = count
    num.append(r)
i = 0
for op in num:
  i +=1
  j = "Case #"+str(i)+": "
  print(j,end="")
  print(op)
```

Comment: Hi Mukund, and welcome to SO. People in general don't like an answer that doesn't have an explanation. Please add a bit of an explanation to the answer. Thanks